# Use polygon to estimate median

Tags: statistics, polygons, median

[image]

Hi guys I really cannot figure out this, is it possible that the median is 150? 
Please help

Comment: How many data items are there?

Comment: Why $150$?  The median should be that height $H$ such that as many students have height $<H$ and half have height $>H$. As you seem to have $400$ students then (ignoring those few with height exactly $H$) we should have exactly $200$  less than $H$ so...

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Median is the height of which $50\%$ of people are shorter than that.

$50\%$ of $400$ people would be $200$ people.

Draw a horizontal line where the cumulative frequency is $200$, read off the value of height where the horizontal line intersect with the curve.

Remark: $150$ is not the answer.